# How to access Django request object in other files

Tags: python, django, request, httprequest, django-channels

I am making a live time Django chat app that uses channels. I have a consumers.py file which handles connections, receiving messages etc... I want to save every new message to my models. In my `Message` model I have three fields (ID, username, message). I save the current users username in `request.session`. How can I access request in consumers.py, to retrieve the current users username and save it to the `Message` model.

I tried accessing the session object from

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
HttpRequest.session
```

but it threw the error:
AttributeError: type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'session'

*Home.py*

```
def home(request):

    name = request.session.get('name')
    if name == None:
        return redirect('login')
    
    context = {
        'name': name
    }
    return render(request, 'App/home.html', context)
```

*Consumers.py*

```
class ChatComsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        #ACCESS REQUEST.SESSION HERE
        Message(message=message, username='???')

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'type':'chat',
            'message':message
        }))
```

*Models.py*

```
class Message(models.Model):
    message_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```